# JavaScript alert has z-index of 0 in new Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, cross-browser, alert

I have a DIV with a `z-index` of *1*. There is a click event handler attached to a sub-element of the DIV.

When the event is raised an alert is shown. In the new Firefox the alert for - whatever reason  - has a `z-index` of *0* and therefore shows **behind** the DIV which has an index of *1*.

What can I do to make sure the alert is visible?

Comment: First of all, you can provide us some code.

Comment: What Firefox version is that?

Comment: @Phrogz - Surely you mean jsfiddle.net. I am working on some code, apparently this wont happen with a simple example, the div with the z-index must be dynamically appended to the DOM.

Comment: Did you try setting the `div`'s `z-index` to `-1`? Also, make sure your `div` has a `position` of `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`.

Comment: @stealthyninja - There is a stack of elements with differing z-index. Regardless of those settings the alert should bubble up and over them. Chrome, ie, and safari do not emulate this issue. My actual code is rather verbose so I am trying to recreate an example.

Comment: @TravisJ Of course I did; how silly of me. If you can't reproduce it in a simple example, then start at the complex and pare it down until you get there. This is what you should do before posting a question in the first place. It can be painful, but it is extremely effective. Either you're going to have your "ah-HA!" moment, or you're going to have a trivial example that will take us 30s to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it yet by creating nodes via JavaScript and appending them to the body.

Comment: @Phrogz - At first it seemed it was simple to reproduce and thought other people may have encountered this. Digging a little deeper it is hard to reproduce. If I can reproduce it, it will be in the form of a full html doc.